# Show each value in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i show values from different columns in new rows?
Lets say i have:

| o_id | type | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product | red |
| 2 | object | green |

And i want my result to look like this:

| o_id | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | product |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | object |
| 2 | green |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach uses a union:

```sql
SELECT o_id, type AS Attribute, 1 AS pos FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT o_id, color, 2 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY o_id, pos;
```